# what’s the difference between “It's always been what I wanted" and “It's always been what I want”?

Tags: difference, past-tense

"It's always been what I wanted"

"It's always been what I want”

The first sentence doesn’t make much sense to me. Wouldn’t the “has always been” imply that’s still what they want ? Why isn’t it “it was always what I wanted” ?

Comment: Where did you find these sentences? They both seem strange. "It's what I've always wanted" would be the normal version.

Comment: I heard it in a movie.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are a little strange.

To answer your question: no, I don't think "has always been" implies that "it" is still what the speaker wants. It may even imply the opposite. The past continuous verb "has been" is, well, past tense. Something that has been happening in the past (the "wanting") might not be happening now, and might not happen in the future.

Your suggestion "It was always what I wanted" has a similar connotation - it *was* what you wanted, but maybe it isn't now.

One nuance is that since the adverb "always" does mean "at all times", it may imply that the "wanting" will continue into the future, even using the past continuous. If that's not your intent, use the past continuous. That leads to the simpler "I'd always wanted it", which I think is more natural than any of your examples. (Without "always", the sentence "It was what I wanted" would strongly imply that you *didn't* want it anymore.)

Finally, if you always wanted it in the past and *do still* want it, I agree with Kate Bunting that "It's what I've always wanted." is more natural.

Comment: Isn’t “has been” used to talk about something that started in the past and is still happening at the present time ? I’m a bit confused, sorry.

Comment: "has been" is indeed used to talk about something that started in the past and continued. But it might not be happening anymore. "Red has been my favorite color for years, but now I think I prefer green." is perfectly normal. But so is "Red has been my favorite color for years, and I think it will be forever."

Comment: To be even more confusing, English has a pluperfect continuous tense, for actions that started sometime in the past, continued for a while, but ended before now. We use "had been": "Red had been my favorite color until November 2016, when I decided it was purple."

Comment: That makes sense. One more question though. Would “red was my favorite color for years” mean the same thing ?